# New Collection interfaces in C# 3.0

Tags: c#, interface, collections

What are the new collection  interfaces available in C# 3.0 ?

**In C# 2.0**

IComparer

IEqualityComparer

IEnumerator

IEnumerable

ICollection

IDictionary

IDictionaryEnumerator

IList.

Answer (score 5):

.NET 3.5 (commonly confused with C# 3.0, although they are completely separate) introduced:

- `IGrouping<TKey,TValue>`
- `ILookup<TKey,TValue>`
- `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`
- `IOrderedQueryable`
- `IOrderedQueryable<T>`
- `IQueryable`
- `IQueryable<T>`
- `IQueryProvider`

and concrete types:

- `HashSet<T>`
- `Lookup<TKey,TValue>`

(and a load of private stuff, but those are the main public ones)

Comment: ...but except for the `HashSet<T>` those are types used for LINQ. Just to be exact. ;)

Answer (score 3):

(Collection) interfaces are defined in the .Net class libraries, not in the C# language.

And in .Net 2.0 your list is missing all the generic interfaces. In .Net 3.0 there weren't any new.

Answer (score 3):

No new interfaces AFAIK, but in the .NET Framework 3.5 (C# 3) you get the new [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) collection class which implements a set (in the System.Core assembly).

Answer (score 2):

You can compare [collection interfaces available in C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections(VS.80).aspx) 
with [collection interfaces available in C# 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections(VS.85).aspx)

no new interface.

Comment: ...and those links only show the non-generic collections, which were in fact already there in .NET 1...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing new in 3.0 when it comes to collection interface.

.NET 3.0 (not just C#) have new Collection Initializers:

```
List<Class1> someClasses = new List<Class1>
         {
            new Class1
            {
               Prop1 = "abc",
               Prop2 = 123
            },
            new Class1
            {
               Prop1 = "xyz",
               Prop2 = 789
            }
         };
```